# Find all strings wanted and select them with QPlainTextEdit::setExtraSelections()

Tags: qt, qt4, selection, qtextedit, qtextdocument

I'm trying to highlight all strings find in a QPlainTextEdit widget , but find() will
only return the first result. The following code isn't working out , why ?

(textview is a class derivated from QPlainTextEdit)

And please don't ask me to use QSyntaxHighlighter to set up colors , it's different.

```
QList<QTextEdit::ExtraSelection> extraSelections;
textview->moveCursor(QTextCursor::Start);
while ( textview->find(key) )
{
    QTextEdit::ExtraSelection extra;
    extra.cursor = textview->textCursor();
    extraSelections.append(extra);
}

textview->setExtraSelections(extraSelections);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's usually good to provide a little more detail about what doesn't work :)

- What text have you tried in the `QPlainTextEdit`?
- What are you using for a `key`?
- Can you clarify what `find` finds when running with the text specified in the first two items above?
- Do you actually end up with a list of extra selections?
- Is the lack of visible highlighting the only thing not working?

I tried your code and it seems to find all the text instances correctly. The problem seems to be that you aren't actually setting any values for the `format` member of `extra`. After you set `extra.cursor`, try setting `extra.format.fontUnderline(true);` just to see if it is having any effect.